# Multiple conditional statements for list comprehension Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, if-statement

I have a list with elements that I want to do operations on with **2 conditions**.

One condition is to multiply a norm function by -1 if the element is negative or leaving the norm function positive if the element is positive.

The list of `values` looks like this:

```
print(values)

-97476.70633454417
-93170.30642401175
-89901.82679086612
-87187.62533194348
-87269.09594982903
-85513.31676486236
-83545.26529198853
-82411.91255123452
-81620.01849452594
```

As you can see they are all negative (in this experiment).

The code looks like this:

```
norm_BIC = [(-1.0) * float(i)/max(values) for i in values if i < 0 or float(i)/max(values) for i in values if i > 0]
```

If I run the code before the `or` statement it works:

```
norm_BIC = [(-1.0) * float(i)/max(values) for i in values if i < 0]
```

Which means it's everything else following that doesn't work because I get an empty list for `norm_BIC` when running after the `or`.

How do I fix this condition?

Comment: wrong word to be thinking of. with "if", you pair an "else".

Comment: At a certain point a list comprehensions starts to hurt readability rather than improve it. You just turn all the bit that is executed on each element of the list into a function. This has 2 main benefits. It takes clutter out of the list comprehension and it also gives the operation a name that helps readers understand what its doing.

Comment: I agree @PaulRooney, although the answer from mfitzp fixed your problem, but you should avoid using list comprehension for such complex logic.

Comment: You can also compute `max(values)` before the loop. Its a linear operation and will return the same value on all iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve "this *or* that" in a list comprehension you need to use an `if` expression. This allows you to add an `else` clause as expected —

```
values = [
    -97476.70633454417,
-93170.30642401175,
-89901.82679086612,
-87187.62533194348,
-87269.09594982903,
-85513.31676486236,
-83545.26529198853,
-82411.91255123452,
-81620.01849452594,

]

norm_BIC = [(-1.0) * float(i)/max(values) if i < 0 else float(i)/max(values) for i in values if i > 0]
```

The syntax here isn't list-comprehension specific, compare to this `if` expression —

```
a = 10 if b < 10 else 20
```

Running your example values without that final `if` i.e.

```
norm_BIC = [(-1.0) * float(i)/max(values) if i < 0 else float(i)/max(values) for i in values]
```

I get the following output.

```
[-1.1942744945724522,
 -1.1415129295794078,
 -1.1014678561595233,
 -1.0682137414339221,
 -1.0692119109931586,
 -1.0477002865491576,
 -1.0235879240531134,
 -1.0097022038381638,
 -1.0]
```

If you just want to ensure the result of your calculation is positive you could use the built-in `abs()` function.

```
norm_BIC = [abs(float(i)/max(values)) for i in values]
```

Comment: This works well. I think what I have above first calculates -1 `for i in values` then tries again `for i in values` so it overrides the first instance.

Comment: I actually deleted the second loop without even noticing :) Yep the inner (left hand) loop will just override the value of `i`, the outer loop is having no effect other than "do this more times".

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are simply filtering out the negative values and turning them positive. The **abs** function takes the absolute value, turning your inputs positive.

would

```
norm_BIC = [ abs(float(i))/max(values) for i in values]
```

not fix your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should use an else clause:

`norm_BIC = [(-1.0) * float(i)/max(values) if i < 0 else float(i)/max(values) for i in values]`

Comment: Sorry, I missed the else order. Now it is corrected.